# How to read INI file entries into a hashtable?

Tags: perl, hash, ini

How do I add entries from an INI file to a hashtable?

My INI file would look like this ...

```
[Channel 0]
Input = 0
Output = 0
CirUpdateRate = 10000 Hz
CirSourceFile = ..\..\MAT\mymodel.mat
CirControlFile = mymodel_0_S1_T4.sim

[Channel 1]
Input = 1
Output = 1
CirUpdateRate = 10000 Hz
CirSourceFile = ..\..\MAT\mymodel.mat
CirControlFile = mymodel_1_S1_T4.sim
```

How can I insert each variable and value into *hash table*.

Will I be able to differentiate or access Variable *Input* under *[Channel 0]* and *Input* Under `[*Channel 1*]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding comment as answer, per request.

You can use [`Config::INI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aINI).

According to the synopsis, you do:

```
use Config::INI::Reader; 
my $config_hash = Config::INI::Reader->read_file('config.ini');
```

Comment: using $config_hash how can I access "Input" in [Channel 0] and [Channel 1].

Comment: `$config_hash->{'Channel 0'}{'Input'}`

Comment: $config_hash--> This variable should be hash variable(Hash variables are preceded by a percent (%) sign)?

Comment: how can I put all the values into hash table?

Comment: `$config_hash` is a [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) to a hash

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. i have read like Hash variables are preceded by a percent (%) sign.

Comment: use Config::INI;
my $config_hash = Config::INI::Reader->read_file('config.ini');

print "\$config_hash->{'Channel 0'}{'Input'} = $config_hash->{'Channel 0'}{'Input'}\n";   if I run this code I am getting error:     E:\perl>perl hash_config.pl
Can't locate Config/INI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl6
lib .) at hash_config.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hash_config.pl line 2.

Comment: @LokeshRGowda use the `cpan` command to install the missing module